# Nested form trouble using Rails and AngularJS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, angularjs, nested-forms

I am fairly new to js and angular but I was trying to get a Rails app working after watching Ryan Bates's railscast on Rails+AngularJS (http://railscasts.com/episodes/405-angularjs?autoplay=true).

I believe what I want to do is fairly simple:  I have a Place model that has many Phones and I want to dynamically be able to add and save phones when creating a new Place.  This type of nested form is fairly easy in Rails alone (with js only creating a new field element when a user adds a Phone), but I want to do this in Angular.

I suppose my question then breaks down into two:
1) What is the best practice of creating nested forms in Rails+AngularJS (or even forms in general)?  Right now I am passing every model to Angular via JSON but is this the best way?

My second question refers to the following code.

I've attempted to do this and I am able to save a Place in angular:

places_controller.rb

```
respond_to :json 
def create
  respond_with Place.create(params[:place])
end
```

_form.html.erb

```
<div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="PlaceCtrl">
  <form ng-submit="addPlace()">
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span2"><label>Name</label></div>
      <div class="span8"><input type="text" class="input-xlarge" ng-model="newPlace.name"></div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Add">
  </form>
</div>
```

place.js.coffee

```
app = angular.module("test", ["ngResource"])

app.factory "Place", ($resource) ->
  $resource("/places/:id", {id: "@id"}, {update: {method: "PUT"}})

app.factory "Phone", ($resource) ->
  $resource("/phones/:id", {id: "@id"}, {update: {method: "PUT"}})

@PlaceCtrl = ($scope, Place, Phone) ->

  $scope.addPlace = ->
    place = Place.save($scope.newPlace)
    console.log place
    $scope.newPlace = {}
```

In place.js.coffee I am able to save Place to the DB in the line (place = Place.save($scope.newPlace)).  I want the id of place so I can append it to all Phones that are dynamically built (because Phones has a FK of place_id that points to a Place).  However if I type in place.id in console, I get an undefined message.  place.name will return the place's name, but id won't work.  If I look at console.log place, however, I see that the id field is returned and populated.

2) How do I get the id field of the place JSON object?  I am almost positive this is possible since Chrome's console returns the id field but place.id won't give me anything.

Thank you in advance for your help.  I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: `location` is bad variable name to use, can run into conflicts with `window.location`. Do a web search for javascript reserved keywords

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.  Location isn't actually the variable I'm using.  I just used it for the example.

Comment: also a bit confusing since I believe you are using `Location` as a reference to a real address field in an object as opposed to browser `location` or angular `$location` which are `url` related. So not entirely sure what you are referring to

Comment: Thanks.  I've replaced the Location variable with Place to make things less confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
$scope.addPlace = ->
  place = Place.save($scope.newPlace) ->
    $scope.newPlaceId = place.id
  console.log place
  $scope.newPlace = {}
```